# Is there a cycle for modulo operation on a floor?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have a floor
$${\left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor},$$

where i varies from 1 to n (n can be upto $10^{10}$), and there's another number given 'm' (m upto $10^{5}$). Does (${\left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor\mod m}$), repeat after some i?

Comment: By repeat you mean $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{i+1} \right\rfloor$ or...?

Comment: Is this an algorithm problem (ie do you want to know the best way to code it)? Or are you hoping for a closed form for $\sum_i \dots\bmod m$?

Comment: @PenasRaul repeat means does the value repeat (is same) after certain i=g, say for example, i mod m repeats after i>m (i = (m+i)(mod m))

Comment: It will be always zero for $i> n$...

Comment: @almagest Actually, it is... not exactly in this form but I reduced it to this possibility, and because n is huge i wanted to know is there a cycle of a lesser length?

Comment: @PenasRaul i varies from 1 to n...mentioned in the question.

Comment: I know, but you want to find a long-run pattern that wont be verified for ever. That usually does not fit if you don't have enough restrictions. You see that between $n$ and $\frac{n}{2}$ it will be $1$

Comment: @PenasRaul Hmmm...I understand, it will be 0 after n, hence can't be cyclic.

Comment: Do you have some idea of the behaviour of the function for small $i$.

Comment: You may want to use the following proposition:
$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i} \right\rfloor$ is the number of non-negative multiples of $i$ that are smaller than $n$.

Comment: @PenasRaul Hmm, No pattern for small i that I can think of. I just want to compute summation of the floor multiplied with an $i^{4}$, modulo m.